# Enabling an attachments field when creating an event in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, attachments, events

I have my site configured with a basic out of the box events app, where the user can click 'add event' and fill in the details of it.

When filling in this info, I want the user to be able to attach documents. This might be for handouts or presentation slides that people attending the event can access.

Within the events content type, I can't find any column for attachments. I've also made sure the attachments option is enabled in the list settings.

Does anyone know how I can enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, When you add OOTB Events app on page it will create one **Events** list in your site.

**To Enable attachments**:

Go to List --> List Settings --> Advanced Settings --> Set `Attachments to list items are:` to `Enabled`.

**Adding Attachments**:

Adding attachments from `Add event` button is not possible as of now as we don't get any attachment field on form.

**Work around**:

Go to Events List --> All Events View --> Select any event --> Click on Items tab from ribbon --> Select Attach File as given below:

[image]

As of now, I am adding attachments like this only. Maybe you will find any better solution if there is any.

**Update**:

Users/Viewers can see the attachments from modern page by clicking the respective event tile:

[image]

Comment: I can use the list view you mentioned above to add attachments, although my issue is that this isn't very intuitive for typical users to find the attachments.

Users would have to double click the row in the list to view the attachments, and I know many of our staff would struggle with this. People would want to click the nice looking event tile in the events web part, view the modern details page, and then see attachments on that same page. I think having to navigate to a list view to open attachments is something people won't get the hang of unfortunately.

Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: You can view the attachments from modern page by clicking Event tile only. But not able upload the attachment from modern page. See my updated answer.

Comment: No need to navigate to a list view to open attachments. You can view/open the attachments from event tile in the events web part itself.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I hadn't seen this before! This makes the usability perfect, thanks Ganesh.

Comment: Welcome.Glad to help.